# How to create a Slick Slider JS slideshow in center mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I want to implement a carousel using the excellent Slick Slider(https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which I have used for images before with no problems. I'm trying to create a 'center mode' slideshow like the example except using several div;

[image: center mode example]

I want to do something like this;

[image]

These are the div's I want to use on codepen here - https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/mdymmgM

```
     <!-- Single Card -->
     <div class="single_slide">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="top-text">
            <h1>DG Aurum</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="view-button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger-opposite shadow btn-sm m-1">Live View</button>
          </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jieUOmw.jpg" class="shadow website-image" alt="website image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when I add the Slick Slider code it messes the layout of the page;

https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/gObWBVG

I've tried looking through the other questions on here but I can't find a solution that works for me, I'm fairly new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you go ahead and load the slick slider css file, that should pretty much fix the problem for you //cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css. I found this out only after making a very barebones version of the slick slider on my own codepen https://codepen.io/dthenley/pen/PowJbgN and proceeding from there. My slider was doing pretty much the same thing yours was right until I added the css code. I also loaded it with a document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick();
});
```